# How to get OAuth token without user consent?

Tags: python, oauth, oauth2client

The standard (for me) OAuth flow is:

1. generate url `flow.step1_get_authorize_url()` and ask user to allow app access
2. get the code
3. get the credentials with `flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)`

But I faced with another service, where I just need to initiate a POST request to `token_uri` with `client_id` and `client_secret` passed as form values (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), `grant_type` is `client_credentials` and `scope` is also passed as form field value.

Does `oauth2client` library supports it?

Comment: Have a look at [`python-social-auth`](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)

Answer (score 0):

Update the grant_type to **implicit**